# Android Shape containing multiple elements

Tags: android, xml

How would one go about drawing a shape, then adding multiple elements to it?

At first I thought I should make use of either a textview, or a button, then simply apply a rectangle as a background. The problem with that is my text is all the same size.

I would also like to eventually add an image to the below purple button.

My end result should look like this:

[image: android container]

What would be very nice, is if there was some sort of container that one could use... unfortunately I am new to android, so I do not know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) and put two TextViews in it:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:height="wrap_content"
 android:width="wrap_content"
 android:padding="20dp">
    <TextView 
     android:text="123,150"
     android:width="wrap_content"
     android:height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
     android:text="TOTAL PAGE VIEWS"
     android:width="wrap_content"
     android:height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is an untested example to give you something to start with, you'll have to adjust font size/color and background yourself.

Comment: it never even crossed my mind to nest linear layouts. I'll try it out quickly

Answer (score 1):

you should look for a layout combinaison :

FrameLayout to have layout superposition

RelativeLayout to position items